# How to run older add-ons in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-3.6

Is there any way to run older add-ons with the newer Firefox 3.6?

If it were possible: is this a good idea, or should we wait for the original developer to release an update? Are there any cons to forcing an addon to run in newer versions of Firefox?

In this case the specific add-on I need is [com tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5003) (to create complex data table mark-up to aid screen reader users to access table data), which by the way is experimental.

Comment: See also "Unsupported Firefox addon" at http://superuser.com/questions/80321/unsupported-firefox-addon

Comment: @fixer1234 I just think that it would be more specific and probably someone from firefox that in charge of this version can help. Because actually I am interested in some tag in StackOverflow and always search that tag in case there's some question that I can help. But I get so sad when one day I search globally and someone post question related to the tag that not marked by that tag. I just want to help, and I didn't know if my edit will bump answered questions too. Sorry, hope never happen again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's better to wait for an updated version of an add-on, certified by the developer to work with the current release of Firefox.

However, some (or even most) add-ons work perfectly even if they've not been updated by the developer. You can skip the compatibility check by going to `about:config`and adding the boolean key `extensions.checkCompatibility.3.6` and set it to `false`. This is also useful if an add-on is not actively maintained anymore.

[image]

Note this method skips the compatibility check for all the extensions installed in Firefox.

Comment: @Snark - cool working

Answer (score 3):

You could force firefox to accept them with [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/6543) or the more featured [Mr Tech Toolkit](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/421)
The outdated extensions will works perfectly, with little bugs or not at all... It will depend of the extension and update...

Answer (score 0):

For those that come across this post you should try [Mozilla Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/). It disables compatibility checking. Doing what Snark said just easier.

It also allows you to report which add-ons work and which do not.